# What does "it's going to be a fast match for team X" mean?

Tags: informal-language

"It's going to be a fast match for Team A."

Does this mean that team A will win? I am not sure what it means, because it's going to be a fast match for both team A or the team team A is playing against regardless of who wins. I was watching an esport match and a member of team B said: "It's going to be a fast match for team A."

Comment: Typically, it would describe the winning team. If they had meant the losing team, they would probably have said something like: *It's going to be a quick defeat for team A.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assumption is correct. Often this means that team A is more likely to win the team B.